# What can I do with bad coffee beans?

Tags: flavor

I recently was about to have a week before I could get my good coffee, so I went to the grocery store and got some of theirs.

Unfortunately, I pulled the lever and got way more grocery store coffee than I could ever need.

It's also terrible. Short of tossing it, is there anything I can do to make it taste better until I get good coffee again?

Comment: What have you tried? What's the nature of the coffee -- dark roast, stale, bland, ...?

Comment: Nothing, I'm new to this and I don't like putting things in my coffee so that's off the table. It's a dark roast and bland.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're wanting ideas that don't include brewing, I would suggest using the coffee grounds as a steak rub or placing the coffee in a compost pile (if you have one).

Also, there are a number of coffee desserts that are sweet enough to hide the taste of bad coffee. I would suggest giving those a try. Some examples would be a mocha fondue, java pie, or layered mocha cheesecake.

Comment: Accepted because this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: [A photo of calf steak in coffee sauce](https://www.instagram.com/p/BSR2GhahuHa/).

Answer (score 15):

Cold brew it! Make sure you start with very cold water and a coarse grind. Cold-temp chemistry has a better chance of taking what's good and leaving what's bad.

Answer (score 10):

If you drink alcohol, you could also try making Kahlúa. Soak coffee beans and vanilla beans in vodka for a while (3-4 weeks), then mix with a simple syrup.  There are plenty of detailed recipes on the web for it.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE, please feel free to take the [tour](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: That's not how you make Kahlua, as far as I'm aware and I'm somewhat locally infamous for my homemade coffee liqueur. But it is a good suggestion, overall. I just don't want OP to think it's quite that simple.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, For us, the recipe above is fine when mixing it with heavy cream and vodka.  But if you're willing to share a better recipe, I'm willing to give it a try. :-)

Comment: @B540Glenn - I make a really strong batch of coffee (1.5 "scoops" per 6 oz "cup" on my drip machine), take that coffee and dissolve brown sugar into it. Once that cools, I add an equal volume of vodka to that sweetened coffee mixture, put it into a glass jug and toss in a vanilla bean that I've sliced open and mashed a bit.  Let it steep for at least a month (don't cover tightly, the glass will break). I add food-grade glycerin for mouth-feel when that's done. For "Tia Maria" mostly the same but with golden rum (not spiced) instead of vodka. Make it in about 4 L batches.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, Thank You for the recipe.  We'll give it a go.

Comment: I'll post how much brewed coffee and brown sugar later. Have to check my notes.

Answer (score 8):

Use them for decoration:
Fill a glass vessel with the beans, stick a candle or tea-light in.

Looks neat, costs nothing extra and if you use a tea-light, the heat of the light will help disperse the scent of the coffee. Replace the beans occasionally.

I have done this in various scales, from tiny coffee-cup-sized arrangements (coffee table for two) to 1-quart glass vases with block candles or small pots of grass where the beans hide the plastic pot (table decoration at a wedding).

This image is from pinterest (source is in the image) as I don't have an own one at hand, but shows exactly what I did:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Ground coffee works well as an odor reducer. You can place it in a sachet or, more simply, in a bowl in the back of your refrigerator to help reduce/eliminate unwanted odors.

Answer (score 4):

**Try a highly-enriched coffee-drink** (with sugar, cream, etc.) like a latte or perhaps [Vietnamese-style iced coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_iced_coffee) with sweetened condensed milk.

As you note in your comment, neither of these are usually my style, either. However, it's a fun change every once in a while. These are what I do when I have a batch of beans that I don't like; it covers up some bitterness, over-roasting, and other off-notes... and since I wouldn't usually consider doing this to beans that I *actually like*, it's merely opportunistic. :)

Answer (score 3):

Mocha cheesecake is already mentioned by Devon. Also, desserts as a category. But, I would like to mention **tiramisu** separately as it is widely known.

Comment: @stephie You're right. I've removed the link to be in line with SA. I assume people could easily Google a recipe, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If they are whole beans, place a layer on a cookie sheet and put them under the broiler for 60 to 90 seconds to wake them up.  I've sometimes had a good result.

Answer (score 0):

This won't fix the coffee but it might not taste as bad. 
Do a normal french press but do a crazy strong ratio like 1:10 1:7 or 1:5!
Filter, then pour some in a cup, maybe half a cup and dilute the rest with hot water.

It won't turn it good but will make it slightly more acceptable than before.