# How to save over extracted coffee made using Dutch cold brew method?

Tags: cold-brew

My wife and I have just started using our Dutch Coffee Maker.

Our virgin experience was quite a failure.

We had some ground coffee (given to us as a gift) that was too fine (espresso grind), and the coffee came out over extracted.

What can we do to save the over extracted coffee? We do not want to throw it away :(

Thanks in advance!

PS: Can we get a dutch-coffee tag? Cold brew is not quite dutch :) or maybe enlighten me on which tags I should use. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the tag. However, it is often hard to fill a specific tag. Keep in mind, there are various other cold-brewing methods, Japanese, immersion, etc. We may end up with a tag explosion if we cannot fill all of them with questions and answers. Btw, it may be better if the question title includes the specific "dutch cold brew" for clarity (Just an opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is discussed in a different context on [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) a while ago. You may want to check the question and relevant answers

- [What can I do with bad coffee beans?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/what-can-i-do-with-bad-coffee-beans)

So, even if you have some over-extracted and maybe somewhat stale coffee, you can easily manage to make tiramisu with it. Or maybe coffee liquor. Or mix with whisky or Cognac kind of strong drinks that you can dilute the over-extracted coffee.

Comment: We eventually made some coffee muffins with the coffee. Generally, I think this is definitely the most sensible solution to deal with bad and badly made coffee

Comment: I'm glad you end up with something. Today, I thought of using over-extracted coffee as a bath for giving aroma to cigars. Why not if you're into?

Comment: Food is what we are into :P dessert is perfect. Maybe someone else can try the cigar idea? (Because i honestly don't know what you are talking about to even comment on it :x)

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you are talking about cold-brewing methods, you will always want coarse ground coffee. If you are set on using this finely ground coffee in your Dutch Coffee Brewer you will want to try a few things.

First, use much less coffee. Yes, it will still over extract over the same time period but will not be as strong. This is probably the worst option.

Second, brew faster. I know that in a Dutch Brewer this is more complicated than just letting it sit for less time. If there is a way to put more water through the grounds in less time, you will want to go with that.

Otherwise, use a different brew method for the finely ground coffee and buy new coffee for your Dutch brewer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That wasn't quite what I was asking for, but it is something I would want to ask again before we go for a new batch of Dutch, so thanks! I have clarified my question because I realised that I was not clear enough :)